# Programmatically build solution with filter

Tags: c#, build, msbuild

After looking all over the Google I found a good way to build a solution. However the solution I want to build also contains unit test projects, which I don't want to include in the build, or if I can't prevent that at least put those binaries in a separate folder. The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Logging;

public class BuildSolution
{
    private readonly string _solutionPath;
    private readonly string _outputPath = "C:\\Temp\\TestBuild\\";
    public BuildSolution(string solutionPath, string outputPath = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputPath))
            _outputPath = outputPath;

        _solutionPath = solutionPath;
        Directory.EnumerateFiles(_outputPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Delete());
    }

    public void Build()
    {
        var pc = new ProjectCollection();

        var globalProps = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { ProjectPropertyNames.Configuration, "Debug" },
            { ProjectPropertyNames.OutputPath, _outputPath },
            { ProjectPropertyNames.EnableNuGetPackageRestore, "true"},
        };

        var targetsToBuild = new[] { "Build" };
        var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(_solutionPath, globalProps, null, targetsToBuild, null);

        var buildParams = new BuildParameters(pc);
        buildParams.Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { new ConsoleLogger(LoggerVerbosity.Minimal) };
        var buildManager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager;
        buildManager.BeginBuild(buildParams);
        var buildSubmission = buildManager.PendBuildRequest(buildRequest);

        buildSubmission.ExecuteAsync(BuildCompleted, null);
        while (!done)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        buildManager.EndBuild();
        Console.WriteLine("OverallResult:{0}", buildSubmission.BuildResult.OverallResult);

    }
    bool done = false;
    private void BuildCompleted(BuildSubmission submission)
    {
        done = submission.IsCompleted;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unused, but I tried it and it gives me back the correct projects but the build fails because of dependant nuget packages
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">path of solution</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFirstLevelProjects(string path)
    {
        foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.csproj"))
            {
                if (!file.Contains("Test"))
                    yield return new FileInfo(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

nothing fancy about it. (I'm playing with the idea of making the build async so I can update status...we'll see about that, I might switch it back to sync). One thing I tried was that instead of putting the solution in the build request, I would build the project collection using the first level projects (I use git with sub-modules, so I don't want to build all the non-relevant sub-modules). The problem with that route was that the build would fail because of nuget packages (not sure why or how to get around that). When I build the solution it builds successfully, but my outputPath also includes the test binaries. My end game is that the output can get copied to a specific folder of mine. I wouldn't mind having the test binaries if I knew I could filter ALL the binaries that are in the test projects... So how? What options do I have?

Answer (score -1):

### Why Not MsBuild?

The easiest way that I can think of to do this is to use MsBuild to do it.

```
msbuild C:\myFolder\mySolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

As for not building the tests, this could now be easily changed from within visual studio

```
Right Click on Solution > Properties > Configuration Properties (on left side)
```

From there you could switch to release mode and uncheck the box next to your test projects. This will tell visual studio that when it does a release build it can skip these projects.

#### Without MsBuild

However, if you wanted to keep building them in the manner that you showed, I would change the assembly name (the dll name) so that you could identify them easily in your favorite scripting language.

```
Right Click on Project > Application Tab (on left side) > Assembly Name Box
```

I would call them something like `SolutionNameSpace.Tests.ProjectUnderTest.dll`.
Then in your build process you can filter out `SolutionNameSpace.Tests.*.dll`. Just be carefull, if you reference testing libraries they could get copied to your output folder also.

Comment: The reason I down voted this is that I am using the MSBuild API, so using msbuild on the command line is not what I want. Also I specify the debug mode on purpose. Lastly this is just a small piece of the puzzle that this program is going to do. Overal the program will build, delete files at destination, copy files over to this destination, and run a few setup programs after the copy is completed. Last part about copying files by name almost works, but there would also be other test binaries (Nunit, Moq, Fluentassertions...etc)